# Mapping Json String Response To Pojo Class

Tags: json, spring-boot, mapper, jsonschema2pojo, response-entity

I want to convert my string response to POJO Class. I have already created a POJO Class named account with the below variable but can't map the response to it.

My Response
[
{
"accountNumber": "12345",
"accountType": "Banking"
},
{
"accountNumber": "12389",
"accountType": "Banking"
},
{
"accountNumber": "12356",
"accountType": "Investment"
}
]

Api Call:

ResponseEntity resp = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);

Comment: did you try ResponseEntity<Account> resp = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Account .class);

Comment: Yeah I used this:
ResponseEntity<Account> resp = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Account .class);

Comment: I am getting response only with:

ResponseEntity<String> resp = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String .class);

Comment: Maybe something is wrong with Accept or ContentType headers! Also, check API to have `Produces JSON`.